# How do you obtain the Google Analytics _ga linker parameter required for cross-domain tracking when using gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, gtag.js

My code uses Javascript window.open to link to another domain.  The url of the target page is dynamically generated. I want to track the analytics across the domains but cannot use the standard "linker" automatic method of gtag,js which automatically adds the _ga parameter to the 'a' tag href attribute or action attribute for a 'form'.  I need to be able to manually add the_ga attribute to the dynamically generated URL which is then used in the window.open.

I have tried creating a dummy 'a href' and then simulating a 'click' using dispatchEvent with a preventDefault in the event handler.  This works for a real click event (the _ga parameter is appended to the href URL which I can then extract and use) but not for a simulated click event with dispatchEvent.

The client ID can be easily obtained using the old analytics.js implementation but I can't find how to do it using gtag.js.

To put it simply, using analytics.js the following code can be used to obtain the "linkerParm" field:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
   var linkerParam = tracker.get('linkerParam');
});
```

What is the gtag.js equivalent?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I’ve figured out how to do this and thought I’d share it here.  This is working for me but I can’t guarantee that it’s the best way.
It appears that gtag.js also loads analytics.js automatically, however it does not do the ‘create’ to set up the tracking ID.
In this example I am assuming that the standard global objects are used, window.dataLayer for gtag.js and window.ga for analytics.js.

```
function getLinkerParam(){
    // our global variables
    window.glpReady = false; // set to true when glpLinkerParam is set
    window.glpLinkerParam = null; // the linkerParam

    // define variables will be used in this function
    var analyticsTimeout = null;
    var timeoutFired = false;
    var timeoutPeriod = 1000;

    // Code to initialse analytics.js if necessary
    function initialiseAnalytics(){
        if (!window.GoogleAnalyticsObject){
            window.GoogleAnalyticsObject = 'ga';
            window.ga = window.ga || function(){
                (window.ga.q = window.ga.q || []).push(arguments);
            };
            window.ga.l = 1 * new Date();
        }
    }

    // initialise analytics.js if necessary
    checker: {
        // is gtag.js installed?
        if (window.dataLayer) { // Yes
            // obtain the tracking ID from the dataLayer
            for (var i = 0; i < window.dataLayer.length; i++){
                if (window.dataLayer[i][0] == 'config') {
                    // initialise the tracking with a create
                    console.log('trackingID='+window.dataLayer[i][1]);
                    initialiseAnalytics();
                    window.ga('create', window.dataLayer[i][1]);
                    break checker;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // gtag.js is NOT installed
            // check for analytics.js installed
            if (window.GoogleAnalyticsObject){
                // analytics.js is installed in it;s own right
                // so the create should already be done.
                break checker;
            }
        }
        console.log('analytics not installed or config tracker id not found');
        window.glpReady = true;
        return;
    } // end checker

    // here analytics.js is defined either in it's own right
    //  or as part of gtag.js. In either case the tracking ID should have been 'created'.
    ga('require', 'linker');
    ga(function(tracker) {
        console.log('Client ID: '+tracker.get('clientId'));
    });

    // set a timeout for the linkerParam
    analyticsTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        timeoutFired = true;
        console.log('get linkerParam timeout fired');
        window.glpReady = true;
        return;
    }, timeoutPeriod);

    // get the linkerParam
    console.log('Get linkerParam');
    ga(function(tracker) {
        var linkerParam = tracker.get('linkerParam');
        console.log('got linkerParam: '+linkerParam);
        clearTimeout(analyticsTimeout);
        window.glpLinkerParam = linkerParam;
        window.glpReady = true;
        return;
    });
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I cant believe that there isn't any documentation on how to handle this with the recommended gtag way of doing things. Analytics is using the ga(linkerParam) so I am just going a head and try to use the gtag get function with the same param name